# How to handle compilation wiht code generated through code generators in .net?

Tags: .net, code-generation

Disclaimer, i am relatively new to .net and am not using it in a professional environment.

I am currently playing around with the newest HotChocolate graphql library for .net which uses code generators to generate class according to .graphql queries etc. present in the project.

What i haven't found a solution for is how to handle building, auto generated code and possibly vcs systems.

The auto generated code is in the obj folder in the project which is usually not part of the code repository and gets kinda often deleted for cleaning reason or whatever. When the obj folder is removed though the project does not compile since obviously there are missing namespaces etc. but to create those files i have to build the project.

Right now the only solution i found is literally removing all references to the generated code then compile and then readding the references.

I am using Rider IDE right now but the issue is the same just using the dotnet commandline tools.

How is everyone solving this issue?